# Optional Filters in Telerik Reporting

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Reporting Control.
I want to  make all Reporting Filters as optional.

The filter can be **DateTime** / **String** / **Bool** / Integer or anything else.
After browsing few of the forums i Set ***AllowBlank*** and ***AllowNull*** properties to True for all filters.

*(I know the ***AllowBlank*** = True is only valid in case of String Type.. But still i Set it for all types for testing)*

But still it is not giving the desired results.

What i want exactly is to show All Report Data by default if no filter value has been assigned.
It works fine if there is only String type filters are provided. But if i add DateTime Filter (*DateTime or Nullable DateTime*)
it won't show the results..
Is it possible to show unfiltered Data on report ???

I also Set the Default Value to Null but still no results.

Please help..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution :)

I was trying to achieve the output via Filter Experssions.

And i got the correct solution from telerik support...

[Optional parameters in telerik reporting](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/optional-filters-in-telerik-reporting.aspx)